# Java Fileinputstream File not found

Tags: java, jsp

"Dbconnection.java" "db.properties" the file can not find the file.
I show you how I get the following files.

My next project directory.

- src

  - DB

    - DbConnection.java
- db.properties

DbConnection.java

```
 public class DBConnection {
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            fis = new FileInputStream("db.properties");
            props.load(fis);
            out.println(props.getProperty("DB_DRIVER_CLASS"));
            // load the Driver Class
            Class.forName(props.getProperty("DB_DRIVER_CLASS"));

            // create the connection now
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty("DB_URL"),
                    props.getProperty("DB_USERNAME"),
                    props.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD"));
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Place your properties file in your resources folder.

Comment: try using the absolute path of the file, not just the name, otherwise put the db.properties where you have the .java files

Comment: Ignore everything else you have been told so far and don't put the `db.properties` file into the JAR file at all. Put it into the current working directory that is used when executing the application. *Or*, put it into the JAR file and load it as a resource, not via `FileInputStream`. NB the `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007.

Answer (score 1):

> fis = new FileInputStream("db.properties");

This line looks for the file under the "home" directory where you run the application. Its equivalent to "./db.properties". If you don't know the root directory of the application, try add debug using this line
*new File(".").getAbsolutePath();* then move your properties file there.

Comment: How's the server started? The location where the user start the application will be your home path.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code please give the complete path of the file(db.properties). That is, for example, if the file is placed in "E" drive "projectA" folder then the path is

```
fis = new FileInputStream("E:/projectA/db.properties");// will work
```

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Don't hard code the path. you should be able to use relative path by getting home path.

Comment: @Minh you are correct. We should not hard code the path but my intention is to tell the "problem with path". The other solution for path is "use of command line arguments".

Comment: Yes, command argument work too. If the properties file doesn't change at all after the deployment, you can push it into the jar or war.